# How to get the URI of a failed ajax request using promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this simple code:

```
var jqXHR = $.getJSON(uri);
jqXHR.done(function (ajax_data) { /* put here your code */ });
jqXHR.fail(function (jqXHR, lvl, msg) {
    console.error(lvl + " with AJAX call: " + msg);
});
```

Is there a way to get `uri` from the `jqXHR` object in the `fail()` handler? There's no `jqXHR.url` attribute, in opposition of the `jqXHR` parameter of the `error()` handler of `$.ajax()`.

I could use `jqXHR.responseText`, but it's the whole response from the server and it's a bit too much for me.

PS: I'm using jQuery promises for ease of use. If I've time I'll use [the Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Comment: This is completely unrelated to promises.

Comment: In this specific case, you can still access `uri` as it's inside a function closure, but I would guess that's not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's no jqXHR.url

Try `this.url`

```js
var jqXHR = $.getJSON("../"); // `uri` : `"../"` 
jqXHR.done(function (ajax_data) { /* put here your code */ });
jqXHR.fail(function (jqXHR, lvl, msg) {
    console.error(lvl + " with AJAX call: " + msg, this.url); // `error with AJAX call:  ../` 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR : `The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to $.ajax in the settings`. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: It seems to me that there's  a little confusion in the JQuery documentation, since the object in the context option and the jqXHR object returned by `$.Ajax()` are called both with the variable name`jqXHR` .

Comment: @LucasMalor _"It seems to me that there's a little confusion in the JQuery documentation, since the object in the context option and the promise-like object returned by $.Ajax() are called both jqXHR"_ Where is `context` same as `jqXHR` ? They appear different; i.e., `context` or `this` could be set to any object, `jqXHR` is jQuery promise object

Comment: Yes, you're right. Probably I read examples on the web that called them with the same name. JQuery docs are correct.